# c# Using variable which is declared in same class but defined in other method

Tags: c#, class, methods, datagridview, textbox

I am rather new to C# programming.
Below codes show how to update a DataGridView Row With TextBoxes In C# and it works perfectly, which I think it should not.

```
int indexRow; // this is declared in Update_DataGridView_Using_TextBoxes class.

indexRow = e.RowIndex; // this is defined in dataGridView1_CellClick method.
```

In btnUpdate_Click method, indexRow is only int, not e.RowIndex which is defined in other method. Right?

Then this code should not work properly, since indexRow in btnUpdate_Click method doesn't mean anything but int.

But in reality, it specifies the exact row which user selected.

I guess that indexRow somehow kept e.RowIndex in it.

How is using variable which is declared in the same class but defined in other method possible?
Or am I missing some point?

Could someone explain how this works?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Update_DataGridView_Using_TextBoxes : Form
    {
        public Update_DataGridView_Using_TextBoxes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        int indexRow;

        private void Update_DataGridView_Using_TextBoxes_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

            table.Rows.Add(1, "First A", "Last A", 10);
            table.Rows.Add(2, "First B", "Last B", 20);
            table.Rows.Add(3, "First C", "Last C", 30);
            table.Rows.Add(4, "First D", "Last D", 40);
            table.Rows.Add(5, "First E", "Last E", 50);
            table.Rows.Add(6, "First F", "Last F", 60);
            table.Rows.Add(7, "First G", "Last G", 70);
            table.Rows.Add(8, "First H", "Last H", 80);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

        }


        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            indexRow = e.RowIndex; 
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[indexRow];

            textBoxID.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBoxFN.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBoxLN.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textBoxAGE.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        }


        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow newDataRow = dataGridView1.Rows[indexRow];
            newDataRow.Cells[0].Value = textBoxID.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[1].Value = textBoxFN.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[2].Value = textBoxLN.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[3].Value = textBoxAGE.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right `e.RowIndex` value is stored in the field of class which is `indexRow`

Comment: I don't understand your question. `indexRow` scope is the whole class, so it is updated each time a cell is clicked and readed in the update method

Comment: Read up on variable scope. Stack Overflow Q&A format is not the right place for open ended questions like this. Voting to close.

Comment: int indexRow; is set for class scope any methods you add in class will be able to access this variable. If you defined this variable within method then scope is different

Comment: First someone has to click cell, then `CellClick` handler runs and store value of `e.RowIndex` (`e` parameter is a struct/class as handler may need many values stored as members of it) in a field. Later the button can be clicked, its `Click` handler uses that index to do something. Clicking button before clicking cell will use `0` index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
indexRow = e.RowIndex;
```

means: put the contents of the `e.RowIndex` variable into the `indexRow` variable.
In programming, `=` means assignment.

And in your case, `indexRow` is a instance field, which means it is kept between invocations of the methods of your class.

Answer (score 0):

IndexRow is a Class variable, so as long as the instance of the class exists the value is retained.

Answer (score 0):

```
int indexRow;
```

Instance variables belong to an instance of a class. Every object has its own copy of the instance variables. (http://www.whatprogramming.com/csharp/variable-types-and-scope/)

is set for class scope any methods you add in class will be able to access this variable. If you defined this variable within method then scope is different

Read this

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

This will give you understanding of scope in C sharp

Comment: Thanks for your answer.